# Java compile error in Intellij IDEA 13.1

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, persistence

I got a code base from a source and trying to build using intellij Idea 13.1. I am a .net guy and trying to set this up. Could  you please help on how to resolve this error. I tried to setup the maven but no luck.

```
Information:Using javac 1.7.0_55 to compile java sources
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'main'
Information:Compilation completed with 100 errors and 0 warnings in 3 sec
Information:100 errors
Information:0 warnings
C:\Java\src\main\java\com\bc\testmod\models\MEntity.java
Error:(3, 1) java: package javax.persistence does not exist
Error:(12, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Entity
Error:(13, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Table
```

Comment: looks like a straightforward dependency problem - "i tried to set up the maven but no luck" - can you expand on that please?

Comment: In Run->edit runconfiguration, I noticed "Make" was there. I changed to maven. Also should I expect javax.persistence file in lib directory?

Comment: @pete23 : There is a file called pom.xml in the root directory. So i thought it uses maven and tried to setup maven. But I was not able to give a working directory for maven, which I dont' know much about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your codebase is maven-based I recommend you to do the following:

1. Set up maven (this includes setting environment variable `M2_HOME` for Maven 2 and `JAVA_HOME`)
2. Get a clean codebase (from VCS for example);
3. Do File -> Open in IntelliJ Idea and open root `pom.xml`;
4. Let maven do its job - creating modules, downloading dependencies, etc. This may take a while.
5. Now you need to build your project. Most likely you'll do that just as you doing it now.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, This worked great! Now I am getting another error which could be related to something else, "Unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]".

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have a JDK defined under:

File -> Project Structure -> SDKs

And that you project is associated with the SDK/JDK here:

File -> Project Structure -> Project -> "Project SDK"

Comment: I would check on maven after you've configured that your JDK/SDK set up is correct